# JavaScript redirect alias to domain

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, path

How do I redirect the alias "u144w" to the domain "https://google.com.br" according to the var ?? Over time I will add more aliases and domains there, but I can't do a window.location that can take the alias from the URL, and redirect to the domain, what should I do? "Location.pathname" will take the alias, then the "getlink" function should look for that alias and its due domain to which it will redirect, and "location.href" will do the work of redirecting. But I am not able to do this, the most I can use is HTML and JavaScript, and no PHP or MySQL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(location.pathname == getlink());
{
    function getlink(){
        var links = {
            "u144w": "https://google.com.br",
    };
    window.location.href == getlink();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var alias_mapping = {
    "u144w": "https://google.com.br"
  }
  if(Object.keys(alias_mapping).includes(location.pathname)){
    window.location.href == alias_mapping[location.pathname];
  }
</script>
```

To add more aliases just extend alias_mapping.

Comment: Do not redirect to the page :(

Comment: Maybe you have to remove some slashes ( / ) from the pathname or add these to the mapping

Comment: Is it possible to make an Index in HTML and JavaScript to redirect?